# MSSQL on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: php, sql-server, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install **sqlsrv** and **pdo_sqlsrv** on Ubuntu 16. I am getting this result

I have already installed MSSQL Express on Ubuntu. I just need to install these two drivers.

```
sudo pecl install pdo_sqlsrv
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_sqlsrv_7_nts.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_sqlsrv_7_nts.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not download from "http://pecl.php.net/get/pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.8.tgz", cannot download "pecl/pdo_sqlsrv" (File http://pecl.php.net:80/get/pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.8.tgz not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
))
Error: cannot download "pecl/pdo_sqlsrv"
Download failed
install failed


sudo pecl install sqlsrv
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_sqlsrv_7_nts.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_sqlsrv_7_nts.so' - /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_sqlsrv_7_nts.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
Could not download from "http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlsrv-4.0.8.tgz", cannot download "pecl/sqlsrv" (File http://pecl.php.net:80/get/sqlsrv-4.0.8.tgz not valid (received: HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
))
Error: cannot download "pecl/sqlsrv"
Download failed
install failed
```

Comment: Are you able to get the file directly from URL ? http://pecl.php.net/get/pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.8.tgz

Comment: yes i have downloaded both files from the URL

Comment: See this link : http://serverfault.com/questions/573307/can-pdo-sqlsrv-driver-be-installed-on-linux-ubuntu-with-php-5-5-3-using-pecl-ins. It seems that you can't use this on Ubuntu or other unix platform.